# Emails has latest changes but for some users it doesn't

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, capistrano

We have a rails application on staging server. Everyday it sends an itinerary email and the year was hardcoded to 2016. Now i changed that to be dynamic and it correctly shows 2017.

But for some users that change and some other changes to that email are not present while for me everything is correct. What would be the cause of this?

I am using Nginx + Capistrano + Rails 5.

Any clues appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Usually, it means that your Background worker, assuming you are using one, it's still sending emails from your old release. I don't know if you know, but Capistrano keeps up to 5 or 3 releases by default and it simply symlinks your current folder with the latest release.

You have to make sure that your Background Job service is restarted and correctly pointing to the latest deploy.

You more than likely have a mix of workers that are working form the current deploy and old ones.

Sorry if it doesn't apply to you, but this was my issue when something like this happened in the past for me.

Comment: thats interesting - we are using sidekiq to process our emails in the background. How can i check which release sidekiq uses though?

Comment: That's exactly what I use and used in the past when I had this issue. I'm not entirely sure to be honest. I'd just kill all workers and start a fresh.

Comment: Thanks i will check that out!